Which sentence sounds more natural to you?
the sentences are as follow:

there are tons of attractions.

there is a lot of attractions.


Are both equally correct? If yes, than which one sounds more natural to you? I guess the latter but would you use first one in some circumstances as well?
And what about the shortened versions like "tons of attractions" and "a lot of attractions" (that's the actuall phrase I'm gonna use, I have very limited space)? Is there the same feeling?

When you talk about shortened versions and limited space, you'll have to tell more about the context. If you walked up to a stranger on the street and blurted these phrases, they would be confused.

For a brochure? You don't need natural, you need zippy:  Got milk? Tons of attractions!

Yes, that's a title for my advertisment. Thanks.

attractions galore

It should be "There are a lot..." in both cases.

Both "tons of" and "a lot of" are rather informal, though they'd be fine in everyday conversation. If you wanted to try something that was more formal and less clumsy, you might use:

There are many attractions.

or:

Many attractions!

If you really want to use one of your shortened versions, go with:

Tons of attractions!

That would be much better than

A lot of attractions.

which sounds unappealing bland.

Yes, it's for advertisment purposes, not everyday conversation. It has to be short and catchy. Thanks man
